# Java - How to append something to a specific line in a file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I was recently working on a project in which I had to overwrite a specific line inside an already existing and populated file. I have read many answers here on StackOverflow which recommend copying the whole content of the file and then edit the specific line using string manipulation and then just rewriting the entire file with the modified data. However, this process is very inefficient when the file is very large. Is there any way this can be achieved without any complications? Thank you.

Comment: No. To change the length of a line, all remaining data in the file needs to be moved. The best way to do that, to prevent corruption, is to copy the file, modifying the line in question as you copy, then delete the original file and rename the copy. There is a reason all the answers you found recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendations are for good reasons, and it is a rare case indeed when you need both the gains in efficiency and still doing this in Java.

That said, you probably want to look at the java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel interface, in Java since 1.7